# Using template's javascript in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, react-redux

I am developing an app in react js for that, I am using an HTML/CSS/Javascript based template. I am trying to create navbar. This includes adding few scripts in the code. How to include the scripts in React JS?
This is my code, which is currently giving error:

```
class TopNavBar extends Component {
state = {
    loading: true
}

componentDidMount() {
    const scripts = [
        '../../assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js',
        '../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        '../../assets/global/plugins/js.cookie.min.js',
        '../../assets/global/scripts/app.min.js'
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) { 
        const addScript = document.createElement('script');
        addScript.setAttribute('src', scripts[i]);
        document.body.appendChild(addScript);
    }

}

render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="page-header navbar navbar-fixed-top">
                <div className="page-header-inner ">
                    <div className="page-logo">
                        <img src={logo } style={{width: '40px', height: '40px'}} alt="logo" className="logo-default" />
                        <div className="menu-toggler sidebar-toggler">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <a href="javascript:;" className="menu-toggler responsive-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}}export default TopNavBar
```

When I run this, I get error:

```
TopNavBar.js:24 GET http://localhost:3000/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED
```

what is the correct way of adding template javascript files in ReactJS app?

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install --save bootstrap
npm install react-cookie --save

Run the above command on the terminal and then include the below line in your script

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import { withCookies, Cookies } from 'react-cookie';

import './app.min.js';
```

Go to this link (https://www.npmjs.com/package/package), you can search all the required package and their documentation.